# Как вывести миниатюру категории товаров в wordpress woocommerce?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Приветствую! Подскажите, как вывести миниатюру категории товаров [image: рис] в wordpress woocommerce на главной странице в описании к товару товаров (ту, что задаем в категориях товаров)
Решение найдено:

```html
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_category_image', 20 );
function woocommerce_category_image() {
 $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );
 $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $product_cats [0]->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
 $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
     if ( $image ) {
      echo '<img class="category-thumb" src="' . $image . '" alt="" />';
 }
  
}
```

Comment: если вывожу здесь 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' - все равно не выходит..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Василий, наткнулся на то что вы ищите вот `WOO Stickers by Webline` плагин ставится из консоли работоспособность проверена.

Comment: оу, @Павел супер! так же можно задавать свои ленточки - да?

Comment: хотя @Павел - для категорий ленточки не выводит, к сожалению..

Answer (score 3):

В woocommerce без использования написания кода делается так.
При добавлении товара есть 2 цены одна обычная другая со скидкой. При создании товара указываешь обе цены. и на миниатюру поверх накладывается надпись РАСПРОДАЖА в овале. В исходниках ищешь надпись РАСПРОДАЖА и стираешь ее. Исходник овала(эта картинка) а лежит она в каталоге woocommerce заменяешь на картинку НОВИНКА. а чтобы она через какое то время исчезала при добавлении материала и цены со скидкой указываешь время действия этой скидки. Надеюсь идея понятна.

Comment: ок, я понял идею, но тут немножко другая задача - ведь новинка и распродажа - это не одно и тоже, так ведь? если мне к примеру еще нужно таким образом (другой ленточкой) указать категорию товаров, то распродажу ведь уже не подсветишь - так ведь?

Comment: да, это использование модуля распродажа в своих немного других целях

Comment: а глянь вверху на код, что я дописал - может подскажешь как его правильно вывести? меня смещает строчка 'woocommerce_archive_description' - думаю, главная станица в woocommerce по-другому называется?

Comment: Не создавай себе лишних проблем.Залез в гугл есть такой плагин  New Product Badge. От него и шагай   [ссылка](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-new-product-badge/)

Comment: для новинок - может быть, но для категорий проблема по-прежнему остается..

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
    if ( is_product_category() ){

        global $wp_query;
        $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();    
        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); 
        echo "<img src='{$image}' alt='' />";
    }
?>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]